# SQL Round Number with Over()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a pretty basic sql query query that is doing a calculation on the total number of records returned from a grouped result set.

```
 SELECT   vco.OutcomeName,
          vco.VersionCompareOutcomeID,
          COUNT(t.OutcomeName) AS Total,
          ROUND(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)), 1) over() AS Percentage
FROM map.VersionCompareOutcome AS vco
LEFT JOIN @temp AS t
ON vco.VersionCompareOutcomeID = t.VersionCompareOutcomeID
GROUP BY vco.OutcomeName, vco.VersionCompareOutcomeID
```

When I try and use the `round` function, I am getting the following error: `The function 'ROUND' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause.`

Without the `round` function, I get the percentage but its not rounded like I am trying to achieve.

My desired outcome would be 2 decimal places: `87.95%` for example.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `ROUND` with [`OVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql), only aggregates, ranking, and analytics functions can be used with over.

But, you can do your aggregation in a subquery or CTE, then do the rounding in the outer query:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(

    SELECT   vco.OutcomeName,
              vco.VersionCompareOutcomeID,
              COUNT(t.OutcomeName) AS Total
    FROM map.VersionCompareOutcome AS vco
    LEFT JOIN @temp AS t ON vco.VersionCompareOutcomeID = t.VersionCompareOutcomeID
    GROUP BY vco.OutcomeName, vco.VersionCompareOutcomeID
)
SELECT
  OutcomeName,
  VersionCompareOutcomeID,
  Total,
  CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(Total * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp), 1) END AS Percentage
FROM CTE
```

Comment: I am trying to integrate this but I am getting an error `Divide by zero error encountered.`. There could be a situation where my total is `0` so I would need to show `0%` as the Percentage. Is this something I can account for in your example?

Comment: Strange, the results keep saying that the records with numbers are `100%`

Comment: @SBB - Sorry it was my fault, try the updated query again :D

Comment: I will need to keep looking into this, the results are coming up as 100% each time for some reason. Possibly miscommunication on what my query is doing.

Comment: @SBB Can you please edit your question with some sample data from both tables?

Comment: The temp table `@temp` has all of the records stored in it that I am working with. I group that data by `versionOutcomeID` & `OutcomeName` to get me the total number of records for each outcome type. From that number, I need to determine what percentage is based on the whole total.

Comment: @SBB Can you show a screenshot of the results of the inner query of the `CTE`??

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/ipkid6/Screen_Shot_2017_10_16_at_11_42_53_AM.png - The count total is also wrong on the ones with `0` results as it should be `0` for the count total.

Comment: @SBB The problem is that `COUNT(t.OutcomeName)` is always the same as `COUNT(*)` which makes sense as you are grouping by `OutcomeName`.